# @Inject instance of @InjectMocks class in @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) is giving null

Tags: junit, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I have a Test class annotated with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) where I have declared @InjectMocks ClassA classA. And there are dependencies annotated with @Inject in ClassA. 
While running my test case, those instances with @Inject is null due to which classA.method() is returning null.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassA.class, LogManager.class})
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.net.ssl.*")
public class TestClass {
   @InjectMocks
   private ClassA classA;
}


@Profile
@Log
@Named
@Configuration
public class ClassA {
  @Inject
  private DependencyClass dependencyClass;
}
```

Since dependecnyClass is null, I'm getting the NullPoiterException.

Answer (score 0):

@Inject Mocks creates an instance of the class and injects any `@Mock`s or `@Spy`'s into that instance. You have declared neither.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassA.class, LogManager.class})
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.net.ssl.*")
public class TestClass {

   // add mock
   @Mock
   private DependencyClass dependencyClass

   @InjectMocks
   private ClassA classA;
}
```